# SQL syntax error with an entity definition in springboot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have defined JPA entity as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateOfCreation;

    public User(){}


    public User(String id, String email, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.dateOfCreation = new Date();
    }
}
```

But it gvies sql syntax error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table user (
        date_of_creation date,
        email varchar(255),
        id varchar(255) not null,
        name varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )" via JDBC [ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 19]
```

What's wrong with my entity definition?

Answer (score 1):

Got ths issue.
'user' is a keyword in postgresql, hence the issue.

Changing 'user' to something else solved the issue.